# Как разбить пробелами, введенные пользователем, дробные числа?

Tags: c#

Есть уже подобный вопрос, но он с целыми числами, ответ на него выглядит так:

```cs
var numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(new[] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(Int32.Parse);
    
foreach(var n in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь переделать код под `double` то у меня выдаёт в цикле `foreach` ошибку

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Я долго пытался разобраться сам, да ничего не помогло. В общем, суть моего вопроса: Как разбить и вывести на несколько строк данные, которые пользователь ввёл через пробел.

Например: `0.3 1.4 2.5`

Comment: В России, дробные числа пишутся через запятую.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не в России, а русском языке

Comment: @return не в русском языке, а в русской локализации

Comment: @return Ну тут я с вами спорить не буду, ибо если идти к таким тонкостям, то можно добраться до культуры того или иного народа или еще "глубже". Я за пример взял страны, а не языки или культуру, как по мне, это более понятное пояснение для многих, простых людей.

Comment: Получилось разобраться?

Answer (score 1):

В русской локализации разделитель дробной части не точка, а запятая.

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(new[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```